# Codeigniter Language File Error

Tags: codeigniter

Can any one please help me about this error when i add some thing facing this error

Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/email_lang.php

Comment: how  are you loading your language

Comment: need to show more detail about your error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have included the language file within /system/language/english?

Comment: yes i have include even when i attached some file there also a error

Comment: please need help is it possible that files corrupted ?

Comment: if you want help you could start by providing the code where you include the file

Comment: hi i include the all language files in system/language/english/

Comment: in config.php $config["Language"]='english';

Comment: please tell me how to ignore this problem all language files load error the application was running correct 1 day before but now its showing errors i did not change anything.